# Implicit differentiation of multiple variable function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$y=x-a\sin(bx)-3$

where $x=x(a,b)$

We have to use implicit differentiation to calculate $\frac{dx}{da}, \frac{dx}{db}$.

This is what I get.

$$\frac{dy}{da} = \frac{dx}{da} - \sin(bx)$$

for $\frac{dx}{da}$ and

$$\frac{dy}{db} = \frac{dx}{db} -ab \cos(bx)\frac{dx}{db}$$

for $\frac{dx}{db}$

Can someone please let me know if I am doing it right. Thanks :)

Comment: You need partial derivatives in there, i.e. $\frac{dx}{da}$ should be $\frac{\partial x}{\partial a}$.

Comment: So it is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your function:
$$
y=x(a,b)-a\sin\left(bx(a,b)\right)-3
$$
to remeber that $x$ is a function of $a$ and $b$

Now you have:
$$
\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial a}= \dfrac{\partial x(a,b)}{\partial a}-\dfrac{\partial }{\partial a} \left[a\sin\left( bx(a,b)\right)   \right]
$$
using the product rule on the second term you find:
$$
\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial a}= \dfrac{\partial x}{\partial a}-\left[\dfrac{\partial a}{\partial a}\sin\left( bx(a,b)\right)+ a \dfrac{\partial}{\partial a}\sin\left( bx(a,b)\right)   \right]
$$

Now using the chain rule:

$$
\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial a}= \dfrac{\partial x}{\partial a}-\sin\left( bx\right)- a b\cos\left( bx\right) \dfrac{\partial x}{\partial a}
$$
In the same manner you can find $\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial b}$

---

EDIT: but rereading i'm not sure this is the question. The OP is a bit confused about $x$ and $y$

Comment: Thanks! One question. Shouldn't it be $dy/da=dx/da - sin/bx)-abcos(bx)dx/da$? The $b$ when you take the partial of the sin term with respect to a

Comment: Yes, I edit and correct my typo.